# Getting error while install expo cli windows

Tags: visual-studio, npm, expo

I try install Expo cli from windows using npm but I get error

This is my code

```
npm install -g expo-cli
```

This the error what I got

```
PS E:\Code\LearnReactNative> npm install -g expo-cli   
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@17.1.1: Switch to 'npm install joi'
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/pinpoint@2.0.0: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/pinpoint'
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/address@4.1.0: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/formula@2.0.0: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/formula'
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://npm.community>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Riky\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-04-12T13_33_17_039Z-debug.log
```

Can someone help me to fix it ? sory I'm new in npm :D

Comment: Don't install it using VS-Code.. Open PowerShell in this location `E:\Code\LearnReactNative` and then run `npm install -g expo-cli` and make sure no other `teminal` or `powershell` is open in background

Answer (score 1):

try below commands:-

```
npm cache clean --f
npm install -g expo-cli
```